# Mongo Admin set with dbAdmin role

Tags: security, mongodb, admin, roles

I am using Mongo 2.4.

I had a single user in the Admin db, and added the role "clusterAdmin", when I meant to add the "userAdmin" role.  Now I can't execute any user-admin based operations.

I tried to update and remove the user, as well as add a new user with "userAdmin" privileges, but because the "clusterAdmin" role does not have privileges to the users collection, I'm out of luck.

How do I bypass the security to add a new user in the Admin db, with "userAdmin" privileges or remove the current "admin" user with only "clusterAdmin" privileges?

Comment: One option can be:

Run mongod without auth mode, and then make those changes.
And again restart mongod on auth mode

Answer (score 0):

happened to me a lot, so I could solve it, remove all Admin users using:

```
use admin
db.system.users.remove();
```

and add a new one as admin

```
db.addUser("name","name);
db.auth("name","name");
```

then you create a user with role clusterAdmin

but you will have to login as admin to do

```
mongo -port 27017 -u name -p name admin
```